# o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor Error processing request | while opening localhost:8080

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle

I am trying to create Jsp's in localhost:8080 using Spring-Boot, Spring-mvc and tomcat-jasper. However when i open localhost:8080/, every time i get an exception which seems related with tomcat-jasper:

`ERROR 5488 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error processing request java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk, org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.EncodedSolidusHandling)'` 
and continues...

I am using 3 files currently and added them here.

#### HomeController.java

```
package com.avalon.springmvcboot;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
       return "index.jsp";
    }
}
```

#### SpringmvcbootApplication.java

```
package com.avalon.springmvcboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringmvcbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringmvcbootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

#### index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head> 
      <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
      <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    Hello World!
  </body>
</html>
```

#### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.avalon'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:9.0.21'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

System Information:  OpenJDK Java 15, Windows 10
IDE: Visual Studio Code

Any helps will be appreciated!
Best regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems wrong tomcat version used at runtime.

`void org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk, org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.EncodedSolidusHandling)` is only available at tomcat 9

[tomcat below 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/UDecoder.html#convert(org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes,%20boolean))

[tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/UDecoder.html#convert-org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk-org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.EncodedSolidusHandling-)

Comment: Yes, when I had changed it to version 9.45, it fixed.